# Is it possible to test Google play billing(In-app billing) on internal testing stage for complete new app(game)?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Recently, I've worked on a game(Unity) that has in-app purchase feature. 
The app is completely rolled-out on the internal testing stage and the status of the app is published. 
The question is can I test Google play Billing of my app on the internal testing stage or should I release the app to closed track to test Google Play Billing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Prepare for testing
To prepare to test your Google Play Billing implementation, perform the following tasks:

**Publish your app to a closed or open testing track in Google Play**. After you publish an app to a testing track it can take a few hours for the app to be available for testers.
Ensure each tester opts-in to your app’s test. On your test’s opt-in URL, your testers will get an explanation of what it means to be a tester and a link to opt-in.

All information here:
[Test Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing)

UPDATE: the documentation has changed and now you can use internal test for inapp billing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed a tutorial that tested in-app billing on the internal testing stage. But the problem was that I haven't register my product IDs on the unity IAP catalog. Anyway I've rolled-out the app to the closed track and successfully tested in app billing. Thank you.

Comment: the documentation is changed and you can use internal test for inapp billing,please update your answer: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test